# How to get return of methods directly

Tags: java, methods

Hello i have this method and i want to get the return of this method ( the **a** variable )
i'm trying to call the method like this x = choosePlanet(scanner); but always i get the same value

Anyone can help me ? thank you

````
 private static Planet choosePlanet(Scanner scan) {

        System.out.println("Voici les planetes Disponible : " + Arrays.toString(Planet.values()));
        List<Planet> PlanetValues = Arrays.asList(Planet.values());
        boolean exist = false;

        Planet a =null;

        do {
            System.out.println("Choisis une planet");
            String choix = scanner.next();


            for (int i = 0; i < PlanetValues.size(); i++) {
                a = PlanetValues.get(i);
                if (a.toString().matches("(?i).*" + choix + ".*") == true) {

                    exist = true ;
                    System.out.println(a.getCommonName());
                }

            }


            } while (exist==false);

        return a;

        }```
````

Comment: Can you tell us a little more? What does Planet look like? Is an enum? What is this same value you are always getting?

Comment: Yes Planet is an enum and i'm getting the last value `public  enum Planet {

    MERCURY(0.387,"MERCURE") , VENUS(0.722,"VÉNUS"), EARTH(1.0,"TERRE"), MARS(1.52,"MARS"), JUPITER(5.20,"JUPITER"),
    SATURN(9.58,"SATURNE"),  URANUS(19.2,"URANUS"),  NEPTUNE(30.1,"NEPTUNE");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your for loop is missing the break statement because of which it iterates through the complete enum and always assigns the last value to the variable a, although there are quite a few things which can be corrected in this piece of code but just to answer your question, here is the correct code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Planet choosePlanet = choosePlanet(scan);

    choosePlanet.getCommonName();

}

private static Planet choosePlanet(Scanner scan) {

    System.out.println("Voici les planetes Disponible : " + Arrays.toString(Planet.values()));
    List<Planet> PlanetValues = Arrays.asList(Planet.values());
    boolean exist = false;

    Planet a = null;

    do {
        System.out.println("Choisis une planet");
        String choix = scan.next();

        for (int i = 0; i < PlanetValues.size(); i++) {
            a = PlanetValues.get(i);
            if (a.toString().matches("(?i).*" + choix + ".*") == true) {

                exist = true;
                System.out.println(a.getCommonName());
                break;
            }

        }

    } while (exist == false);

    return a;

}

enum Planet {
    EARTH("earth"), MARS("mars"),JUPITER("jupiter"), SATRUN("satrun");

    private String commonName;

    Planet(String string) {
        this.commonName = string;
    }

    public String getCommonName() {
        return commonName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it's works i wish u the best :)